# Visually edit C# imagemap control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, imagemap

I just discovered the imagemap control in Visual Studio 2008.
I'm familiar with the imagemap concept from HTML, I'm just used to having editors that allow you to select areas visually, like drawing a hotspot on the image itself, and the software generates the HTML itself.
But I can't do that in Visual Studio, and I have about 20 different circular hotspots to create.. also I have no idea on how to easily detect coordinates (X & Y).
Any tips? Advice? Ideas?

Added in edit - Also, is there a way to add code to each hotspot in an imagemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK there is no designer support for hotspots - I use a piece of paper.

Concerning the code, you'll have to set HotSpotMode="PostBack" PostBackValue="HS1" for each hotspot and use a switch statement in ImageMap1_Click to react to the different Postback values.

Answer (score -1):

You can capture mouse clicks on the imagemap using jQuery, then pass the `x, y` coordinates of mouseposition to textbox. At the end you can add captured areas to your imagemap.